# How to get the return code of a shell script in lua?

Tags: shell, lua, exit

I'm executing a script in lua:

```
os.execute("sh manager/scripts/update_system.sh" .. " " .. f)
```

And I want to get the output of the script( if exit status is 7 returns 7).

I tried

```
local output = os.execute("sh manager/scripts/update_system.sh" .. " " .. f)
print(output)
```

but it returns some weird numbers like 512

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: `os.execute` return values are different on [5.1](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-os.execute) and [5.2](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-os.execute)

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff indeed! It was like "we've decided to completely change the function interface from `int os.execute(string)` to `{bool,string,int} os.execute(string)`, so let's just do a **minor** version bump to warn the users that every single line of code that uses that function and perform error checking will crash."

Comment: @user1593842 - Minor Lua versions are incompatible.  Actually, Lua 5.1 and Lua 5.2 are different languages, and it's not an easy job to migrate programs between the two versions.  It is mentioned in the manual.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the outputs of os.execute are all 256 multiples. Don't ask me why, it must be a bug.

So I did this:

```
local exit = os.execute("sh manager/scripts/update_system.sh" .. " " .. f)
 local value = exit / 256
 print(value)
```

It works but I wonder if there is another solution.

Comment: It isn't a bug. It is lua returning the raw value from [`system`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system). See also [`wait`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) for `WEXITSTATUS`.

Comment: As Egor said, os.execute has changed from lua 5.2 onwards. It now returns 3 value, and you can get the underlying process return code by looking at the third return value. However, it seems -- on Linux, at least --, that the return code is the same as what would "echo $?" provide (a value between 0 and 255). The third return value seems to be the return code, modulo 256.

Answer (score -1):

This works for both Lua 5.1 and Lua 5.2

```
exit_code = io.popen'your_command \necho _$?':read'*a':match'.*%D(%d+)'+0
```

Comment: JM2CW: I'd like to +1 but such one-liner obfuscates the answer. Code shown on SO should favor clarity over brevity. It should not be as condensed as the programming language will allow.