# Bash script is not being executed on .lua, exit status 7 (Arg list too long)

Tags: bash, shell, lua

The `.lua` file is being executed because i saw the strings from `m.log()` in my log but the bash code is not being executed. Why? There's something i'm missing? Also there's no errors in the logs about the command in `os.execute()`.

```
#!/usr/bin/lua

function main()
m.log(1,"Starting script execution \n")
os.execute ("route add xx.xxx.xxx.xxx reject")
## i also tried os.execute ("/path/to/file.sh") and giving permision to execute with chmod +x filename.sh
m.log(1,"Script execution finished\n")
end
```

NOTE: I executed the command from `os.execute()` directly in my Command Prompt, and the IP was added to the `route`, so there's something wrong in my lua code...

I changed the permisions to 777 from the folder/file that have the `.lua` and `.sh` file only to test if it was a permision issue, and nothing changed, i also tried to change the owner and usergroup.

**Edit -**
This one bellow was not working because it was on the `/root/` folder, so i needed to moved it to `/var/www/`.

```
os.execute ("/path/to/file.sh")
```

But the bash code is not being executed, the `os.execute` is returning exit status 7 (Arg list too long), I searched about it and i realized that it's because the entire bash code is being executed inside quote marks: [Why do I get "/bin/sh: Argument list too long" when passing quoted arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475221/why-do-i-get-bin-sh-argument-list-too-long-when-passing-quoted-arguments)

How can i fix it?

Comment: Try `/sbin/route` instead of `route` inside `os.execute()`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Did not work, and the current problem i'm facing is about the exit status 7 (Arg list too long)

Comment: Try `os.execute ("/bin/bash /path/to/file.sh")`

Comment: The problem was because i needed to execute the `.sh` with `sudo`, and it did not has root privileges.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the result of [os.execute](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-os.execute), as it returns the exit status of the command as one of the results.

You can also use [io.popen](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-io.popen) to run your script and check the generated output.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/YB3QGurH This is the exit status, right? So what should i do with it? It did not show errors. And about the `io.open` i tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9676174/10286151, i also tried other methods that i found in forums, none worked.

Comment: `When called without a command, os.execute returns a boolean that is true if a shell is available. ` I did checked it and it returned true. But i don't know what `shell is available` supposed to mean

Comment: Looks like the exit status, but I would print all values returned from `os.execute`. What OS are you on? Assuming 1792 needs to be divided by 256, looks like the actual error returned is 7, which is "Arg list too long" (going by http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html), but this doesn't seem to be right in your case.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/LnQk9wj3 i did the same but using the path to the `.sh` file instead, the exit code was 32256%256 = 126, and on your link the list error range is 1-124, my OS is ubuntu 16. I also tested this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/23833013/10286151 the exit code seems to be correct, exit code is 7 when i put the bash code directly in the function `io.open`

Comment: "If a command is found but is not executable, the return status is 126." according to https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html

Comment: @nobody, did you find the reason? I don't have any further suggestions based on your updated answer, other than to experiment what commands are being executed to see what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Yes, i said it in the comment above. I was getting status 7 because the `route` needed to be executed as root. And I realized that many events can return status 7.